# SQLite console appears after running C++ application

Tags: c++, sqlite

my problem is that when I run the main .cpp file the SQLite console appears and waits for commands instead of performing the operations in the code and producing some output. What is the problem? 
Okay, the code was just a test to make sure everything works:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_open("Database.sqlite", &database);
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "CREATE TABLE a (b INTEGER, c INTEGER);", -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    cout << cols;

    int result = sqlite3_step(statement);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add some code and explain a bit more :)

Comment: Can you please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: i've added the code, but i think this is not so important because whatever the code is, this problem appears

Comment: I don't think this is a coding problem, but relates to how you are building/running your code.

Comment: I create a C++ Console Application project in VS2012 and then run it as usually.

Comment: There's nothing that seems to be wrong with you code (except that you should `#include "stdafh.h"` _first_). You might want to flush `cout` though (using e.g. `std::endl`) but it shouldn't matter since `cout` will be flushed anyway when your program ends.

Comment: I just tried your code on Ubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3. Everything works fine. You should test the `result` code, but otherwise the code looks ok.

Comment: How did you include the code for sqlite? Kinda sounds like you included the code for sqlite's shell code and that code is being run instead of yours.

Comment: well, i created a project  without precompiled headers since otherwise it would give out an error, then i included sqlite3.h & sqlite3ext.h into the headers folder and shell.c and sqlite3.c files in the "Source files" folder. I bet there's something wrong with the configuration. Perhaps i should get rid of that shell.c?

Comment: okay so removing shell.c solved the problem, thanks everybody for responding to my question and especially Joel Lucsy for giving me that hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include sqlite's shell.c into your project.